# Extract shortcode for each section of "My account" page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shortcode

Good evening,

I need to extract the shortcode for each section of "My Account" page in WooCommerce:

1. Dashboard
2. Orders
3. Addresses
4. Account details
5. Logout

In have tried this code snippet:

```
add_shortcode('my_account_section', 'shortcode_my_account_section');
function shortcode_my_account_section($atts) {
extract(shortcode_atts(['section' => ''], $atts));
ob_start();
do_action('woocommerce_account_'.$section.'_endpoint');
return ob_get_clean();
}
```

With this snippet:

[my_account_section section="orders"]

It works fine but for the other section, no result.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which one is not working and how you added the shortcode.?

Comment: So what values for `section` did you use for the other cases? Do they match the hooks names listed at the bottom of https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_account_(key)_endpoint ?

Comment: @mujuonly The only shortcode that works is that of the orders. I added the shortcode in a shortcode bloc with the site builder "Oxygen".

Comment: @Kambro - Show your other shortcodes usage

Comment: @CBroe In the other cases, I added : "dashboard" "addresses" "account details" and "logout" I tried the hooks names of the link you gave me, but without more success.

Comment: @mujuonly Here they are: [my_account_section section="dashboard"] [my_account_section section="addresses"] [my_account_section section="account details"] [my_account_section section="logout"] Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below shortcode to render my-account sections.

```
[my_account_section section="orders"]
[my_account_section section="edit-address"]
[my_account_section section="edit-account"]
```

Comment: Thank you ; the shortcodes you gave me works fine! Only the shortcodes for dashboard and logging out are missing.

Comment: Logout doesn’t have an endpoint do_action. It's simply a logout link `if ( 'dashboard' === $endpoint ) {
  return wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
 }

 if ( 'customer-logout' === $endpoint ) {
  return wc_logout_url();
 }`

Comment: Thank you, you're right. But the given code don't work. I presume I did not fill everything that was required. Excuse-me, I'm a newbie.